# (AngularFire2 + Ionic3)Recuperar valor de uma child para uma variável

Tags: ionic, firebase, ionic3, angular-fire-2

Bom dia pessoal, sou novo no ramo Ionic/AngularFire e estou enfrentando uma grande dificuldade para recuperar o valor de uma child dentro do meu Database. A idéia é pegar esse valor e armazenar em uma variável para poder fazer algumas comparações dentro do meu código.

**Este é meu Database**]
[image]

**Esta é minha tentativa de recuperação do valor da child "typeuser"**
[image]

Comment: Evite apresentar o seu código através de imagens.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Leandro! Era meu primeiro post, não conhecia as ferramentas que o site possui para publicar o código! Agora já conheço!

Answer (score 0):

tenta assim:

```
this.db.object('clientes/'+this.id)
.valueChanges()
.subscribe(statususer => {
    var statusCliente = statususer.status;
});
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, consegui chegar ao valor com o código que vc me passou, só precisei implementar o console.log. Porém ainda deu um erro lá, adicionei como resposta, será que poderia me ajudar?

Comment: mas qual foi o erro? printa a tela do erro se possível

Comment: Adicionei ele aí como resposta agora.

Comment: qual o valor de this.userId? verifica isso tentando algo assim: console.log('Usuários/'+this.userId+'/Dados Pessoais/typeuser');

Comment: Consegui. Vou postar a solução que encontrei nas respostas! Obrigado aí pela força Ronaldo Freitas! Vlw msm!

Answer (score 0):

Quando atribui o userId manualmente dentro do caminho

```
this.afData.object('Usuários/pqMaisUMrWUrk8v8TZmvzQjd1H82/Dados Pessoais/typeuser')
```

Função completa:

```
constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
private afData: AngularFireDatabase,
private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if(user) this.userId = user.uid})
  this.afData.object('Usuários/pqMaisUMrWUrk8v8TZmvzQjd1H82/Dados Pessoais/typeuser')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(dataclient=>{
        console.log(dataclient)
        this.typeUser=dataclient;
      });
  }
```

consigo receber o valor da child "typeuser" e armazená-lo em uma variável. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando coloco a variável userId (como descrito abaixo) recebo "null" como retorno.

```
this.afData.object('Usuários/'+this.userId+'/Dados Pessoais/typeuser')
```

Função completa:

```
  constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
private afData: AngularFireDatabase,
private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if(user) this.userId = user.uid})
  this.afData.object('Usuários/'+this.userId+'/Dados Pessoais/typeuser')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(dataclient=>{
        console.log(dataclient)
        this.typeUser=dataclient;
      });
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depois de tentar várias vezes realizando testes de verificação dos valores das variáveis na página HTML descobri que os valores estavam ali nas variáveis porém não estavam sendo repassados para as outras funções.
Consegui resolver deixando apenas a função getIdUser dentro do constructor e dentro dela chamando as demais e deu certo!

```
constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
private afData: AngularFireDatabase,
private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if(user) this.userId = user.uid
    this.searchTypeUser()});
    }

    searchTypeUser(){
      this.afData.object('Usuários/'+this.userId+'/Dados Pessoais/typeuser')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(dataclient=>{
        console.log(dataclient)
        this.typeUser=dataclient
        this.redirect()});
    }

    redirect(){
      if (this.typeUser=='client') {
        this.navCtrl.push(ClientPage)
      }if(this.typeUser=='coordinator'){
        this.navCtrl.push(CoordinatorPage)        
      }if(this.typeUser=='promoter'){
        this.navCtrl.push(PromoterPage)
      }if(this.typeUser=='admin'){
        this.navCtrl.push(ConsolePage)
      }
    }
```